# Install And Configure Samba on Difrrent Drives

Tags: samba

Hellow Guys,

Mi situation is This: I have 3 Difrrent Drives . One 250 Gb that runs Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 and 2  2TB WD Red for Samba. I want to install and configure samba on these 2 tb Drives. I follow some tuturial how to install samba and configure it but i end up installed on 250 Gb that has the OS. I would like to install it and share my files on these 2 tb drives. 
Any help or link will be apreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Software is installed in various standard places, including '/bin`,`/usr/bin' and `/opt/...` This i as designed. You can't easily change this, and since theese packages don't take much space it is not a problem.

You configure Samba to share the directories (path's) you want. So if your 2 TB disks is mounted at `/media/disk1` and `/media/disk2` you will have to share those two in Samba.